# Math operation in SQL?

Tags: sql, perl, performance, sql-server-2000

I'm creating an application to calculate some Login -Logouts on a call center, basically what I do is to get an interval within times.

Which would be best: 
to get the interval on the DB Server (SQL Server 2000),
or in the code itself (Perl)?
I'm running on Windows Server 2003.

Basically the operation is:
 Login-Logout + 1
But there are about 1 000 000 rows on each query.

P.S I do know how to do it, what I'm wondering is what would be a best practice.

This is my actual query :

```
select S.Ident,S.Dateissued , 
       S.LoginMin,S.LogoutMin ,
       E.Exc_Name , 
       CAST(CAST( (LoginMin / 60 + (LoginMin % 60) / 100.0)  as int ) AS varchar ) + ':'   +  CASE WHEN LoginMin % 60 < 10 THEN '0'+ CAST(LoginMin % 60 AS varchar) ELSE CAST(LoginMin % 60 AS varchar) END ,  
       CAST(CAST( (LogoutMin / 60 + (LogoutMin % 60) / 100.0)  as int ) AS varchar ) + ':'   +  CASE WHEN LogoutMin % 60 < 10 THEN '0'+ CAST(LogoutMin % 60 AS varchar) ELSE CAST(LogoutMin % 60 AS varchar) END,
       (LogoutMin-LoginMin)+1 as Mins,
       E.Exc_ID,action
FROM igp_ScheduleLoginLogout S INNER JOIN igp_ExemptionsCatalog E
ON S.Exc_ID = E.Exc_ID
where ident=$ident
and dateissued between '$dateissued' and '$dateissued2'"
```

Comment: Do you have data model that will help better answer your question?

Comment: Just a sidenote: The Casts you're doing for displaying hh:mm are computationally much more expensive than your simple calculation, by  orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

If you are doing math on a **set** of data (like your 1 million row example), SQL is optimized for set-based operations.

If you are doing math on an iterative, row-by-row basis, your calling application or script is probably best.

Comment: It is indeed a row-by-row basis! Thanks for the advise!

Comment: @Rafael: the best way to thank people on this site is to accept the answer that worked best for you.

Comment: @Stingy : Not really
Definition of ADVISE
transitive verb
1
a : to give (someone) a recommendation about what should be done : to  <advise her to try a drier climate>

Comment: If you are doing math on an iterative, row-by-row basis, you should consider if you can do it on a set (with a single SQL statement) instead.

Comment: @Rafael: Advice is a noun, advise is a verb. Look up the difference and compare your usage.

Comment: @Paul: Ok Im sorry, english is not my native language but thanks for the advice :) see I'm already learning

Answer (score 1):

Generally aggregating on the server and returning the final answer is faster than pulling all of the rows to an application and chugging through them there.

Comment: I see! However I still have to bring the other 2 rows :

Answer (score 0):

Generally the answer is that if you can do the calculation as part of the SQL query without having to change the form of the query, and if your application-layer code supports it (e.g. you aren't using an ORM that makes it difficult) then you may as well do the query as part of the SQL. With such a simple calculation it's not likely to make much difference, so you should write whatever leads to the most maintainable code.

As with any performance question, the real answer is to benchmark it yourself. Answers on StackOverflow can only get you so far, since so many factors can affect performance in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

It partially depends on how scalable this has to be.

With 1 client and 1 server, as other have noted, doing it in SQL may be faster (but benchmark youself!)

With several clients and 1 server (either now or in projection), you scale the calculations per client and offload ALL of them from 1 server, so the server load is dramatically lower. In this case, do the calculation in the client (or app server).